# Angular 5 moving component / dom manipulations

Tags: angular, flickity

I'm trying to use a slider-lib [flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/api.html#getcellelements) in Angular 5, but fail because it does some dom manipulations, angular doesn't like.

In their description you have to use it like this:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <div>slide 1</div>
  <div>slide 2</div>
<div>
```

This works but I wan't to use it with angulars `*ngFor` like:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <div *ngFor="let slide of slides;">slide </div>
<div>
```

But because flickity add's to divs `flickity-viewport` and `flickity-slider`, and puts the slides in there, angular doesn't like it.

```
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="flickity-viewport">
    <div class="flickity-slider">
    since the two outer divs are created dynamically by the lib, the items in here are falling out back to the `.gallery` div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So while sliding, the `slides` are getting removed from `.flickity-slider` and added in `.gallery` (probably because the *ngFor was initialized in the `.gallery`).

Any idea I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular was rebuilding the DOM, because I had not used a `trackBy` function. When using it, it works without rebuilding the DOM and `flickity` works with *ngFor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the encapsulation on the component to **ViewEncapsulation.None**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Comment: Good try, but sadly same effect happens.